# For which scalars is this matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For which scalars $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&-1\\1&a\end{bmatrix}$ invertible? What is the answer if $a\in \mathbb{C}$?

I know how to solve this with determinants. However, we are not allowed to use them in this task. How do I show this?

Comment: What are you allowed to use? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried elementary row operations?

Comment: Yes, but can't quite figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using elementary row operations we can determine the rank:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & -1 \\
1 & a
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
a & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & -1-a^2
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & 1+a^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence,
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }1+a^2=0, \\ 2 & \text{if }1+a^2\neq 0.\end{cases}
$$
We conclude that $A$ is invertible iff $1+a^2\neq 0$.

Comment: We've not yet had about ranks yet. Is there another way to solve this?